# Load balancing / redundancy for Windows domain controllers FOR LDAP/LDAPS ONLY

Tags: dns, active-directory

Where I work there are many apps that query Active Directory using LDAP/LDAPS and which can only be configured with a single name to query.

Obviously if that name is a domain controller there's a single point of failure. What's the best way of achieving redundancy? I think I need something like a load balancer that knows if a domain controller's up or down. The domain controllers must be in separate sites. A solution would also need to be handle LDAPS.

We're currently trying a DNS alias ldap. which is DNS round robin ie it resolves to multiple domain controllers, combined with a BMC Patrol script that polls the domain controllers and deletes their ldap. record if they're offline. But in testing we're having a peculiar (to me) result where an ldap query to ldap. succeeds and the domain controller sends the answer, but then sends a referral to a name LDAP://domaindnszones. and a couple of (unix) apps crack up at that point and try to do the second query authenticating as "root", which fails.

I'd be grateful for any thoughts... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this with a load balancer is not uncommon if you have apps that just want to do simple binds. You'll want to load balance port 636 for LDAP/S if you can make that a requirement for your apps. If you have multiple domains in your forest, port 3269 is the global catalog LDAP/S port.

As far as certificates go, you have two options:

1. Put an SSL cert on each DC with just the DC's hostname, and then put a cert on the load balancer for the VIP (e.g. ldap.contoso.com). Have the load balancer do re-encryption.
2. Put an SSL cert on each DC that has the DC's hostname in it, and a subject alternate name (SAN) of ldap.contoso.com. Simply pass the traffic through the load balancer.

For #2, it's important to note that AD will only bind to a certificate that has the DC's hostname either in the subject name field or the /first/ subject alternate name field.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian, that was a very helpful answer.